# Launch multiple simultaneous rsync processes to copy one file in every sub-directory (maxdepth -1)

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, rsync

I would like to transform a plain rsync command, which copies one file (robots.txt) to the target sub-folders situated at 1 level depth (maxdepth -1) into a multi-threaded command, using parallel, or any other solution which speeds up transfer :

Plain rsync:

```
find /home/targetfolders* -maxdepth 1 -type d  -exec rsync -av /home/source/utils/robots.txt {} \;
```

What would be the best solution ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It is unlikely to be much faster than doing it serially.

Comment: What do you mean by serially? Using plane cp command? 

`find /var/www/* -maxdepth 1 -type d  -exec cp /home/wiserwires/utils/robots.txt {} \;`

Comment: By *"serially"*, I mean *"one after the other, that is, not in parallel"*.

Comment: There are more than 20k subfolders, I've already deployed robots.txt using the plain command but I'm sure that using 16 parallel threads would be much faster. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I think this is a good idea, but if you want to do it with **GNU Parallel**, you would be looking at something like this:

```
find /home/targetfolders* -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | 
  parallel -j 16 -0 rsync -av /home/source/utils/robots.txt {}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks! Definitely there is a speed improvement, it's important to adjust the core/process ratio.

Comment: Ok, good. If you do this often, it might be worth writing a little Perl script and calliing that instead of `rsync`. It would take a whole list of directories as parameters and then you would call it using `parallel -0 -X script.pl`. That way rather than executing a whole new `rsync` process for each file, you would just call a Perl function instead and it should be lighter weight.